# How to properly unstack or reshape my dataset?

Tags: python, dataframe, reshape

I'm starting with the following table:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cust 1 | xxxxxx | ppppp |
| cust 1 | yyyyyy | ppppp |
| cust 1 | zzzzzz | uuuuu |
| cust 2 | aaaaaa |  |
| cust 3 |  | bbbbb |
| cust 3 | cccccc | ddddd |

And I want to convert it to the following format:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column B2 | Column C2 | Column B3 | Column C3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cust 1 | xxxxxx | ppppp | yyyyyy | ppppp | zzzzzz | uuuuu |
| cust 2 | aaaaaa |  |  |  |  |  |
| cust 3 |  | bbbbb | cccccc | ddddd |  |  |

How do I do this in Python?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using a Pandas-dataframe. With `df` your dataframe you could try the following:

```py
result = (
    df.melt(id_vars="Column A", var_name="columns")
    .assign(columns=lambda df:
        df["columns"]
        + df.groupby(["Column A", "columns"]).cumcount().add(1).astype("str")
    )
    .pivot(index="Column A", columns="columns")
    .droplevel(level=0, axis=1).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
result = result[sorted(result.columns, key=lambda c: c[-1])].reset_index()
```

Result for the sample dataframe:

```
  Column A Column B1 Column C1 Column B2 Column C2 Column B3 Column C3
0   cust 1    xxxxxx     ppppp    yyyyyy     ppppp    zzzzzz     uuuuu
1   cust 2    aaaaaa       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2   cust 3       NaN     bbbbb    cccccc     ddddd       NaN       NaN
```